# Web page not loading on WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm a beginner in Android Development. So I'm searching online for tutorials to learn about.I got this code that I was trying on my computer, when I run the code and view the App, it says that the webpage is not available,so I added the manifest file, but it still says the same thing

The code is given below:

```
package com.paresh.webviewclientdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {
    WebView web;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }

   public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the manifest file:

```
<users-permission android:name="permission.INTERNET" />
```

But even after this,the Android web view webpage does not load, I cannot find the error. Help me find it. Do I need to add something else, or is there an error in the existing files that I have given

Answer (score 0):

try these codes instead.

class:

```
public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
private String url = "https://www.google.com";
private ProgressBar progressBar;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);

}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 10000);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminate="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```